# My buddy benched 450, is this possible with no steroids?

Tags: weightlifting, strength, bench-press

Although he is a kind friend of mine and I do not believe him to be a steroid user or have seen any symptoms(back acne, packing on mass ridiculously fast, etc.), my buddy in the gym in my high school benched 450. He is 18 years old, was captain of the football team, about 6'4, and 250 Ibs. So yeah, pretty big dude. But he hit 450 somehow, and it astounds me how he could've climbed to near-Olympic level weight without years of training and severe dedication. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible? Sure. At 18? Plausible. Without years of training? Unlikely. Did you witness this lift? Either your friend is fibbing or you're underestimating how long he's been training.

Comment: @Alex L: I did not witness the lift, but I have heard it from trusted adults who run the facility and the person themselves. Also, I believe he trained for... 3 years?

Comment: Assuming he went through puberty around the same time most guys do, then 3 years is, in theory, plenty of time.

Comment: Keep in mind, going through puberty is similar to using anabolic steroids (i.e. significant increase in testosterone).

Comment: 204kg in real money

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possile, with good genetics and certain body leverage advantage.
Look up Jesse Norris and Larry Williams.

He might not be good at other things though.